# Array of protocol type

Tags: swift, generics

I have checked all answers about this problem on stackoverflow, but still can not figure out how to fix this. 
My model looks like this

```
protocol Commandable: Equatable {
    var condition: Condition? {get set}

    func execute() -> SKAction
}
```

And 3 structs which implement this protocol

```
struct MoveCommand: Commandable {

    var movingVector: CGVector!

    //MARK: - Commandable

    var condition: Condition?
    func execute() -> SKAction {
       ...
    }
}

extension MoveCommand {
    // MARK:- Equatable

    static func ==(lhs: MoveCommand, rhs: MoveCommand) -> Bool {
        return lhs.movingVector == rhs.movingVector && lhs.condition == rhs.condition
    }
}
```

---

```
struct RotateCommand: Commandable {
    var side: RotationSide!

    // MARK: - Commandable

    var condition: Condition?
    func execute() -> SKAction {
        ...
    }
}

extension RotateCommand {
    // MARK: - Equatable
    static func ==(lhs: RotateCommand, rhs: RotateCommand) -> Bool {
        return lhs.side == rhs.side && lhs.condition == rhs.condition
    }
}
```

---

The problems start when I am trying to create third structure which has array of [Commandable]:

```
struct FunctionCommand: Commandable {
    var commands = [Commandable]()
```

The compiler output: `Protocol 'Commandable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`. Then i rewrote my struct in this way:

```
struct FunctionCommand<T : Equatable>: Commandable {
    var commands = [T]()
```

I resolve this problem but new problem has appeared. Now i can't create `FunctionCommand` with instances of Rotate and Move command, only with instances of one of them :( :

```
let f = FunctionCommand(commands: [MoveCommand(movingVector: .zero, condition: nil), 
RotateCommand(side: .left, condition: nil)], condition: nil)
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

**Update**: That article helped me to figure out - https://krakendev.io/blog/generic-protocols-and-their-shortcomings

Comment: Just curious, why are you using structs and protocols when subclassing would easily solve this?

Comment: @Carter Swift don't have abstract classes, also Swift is protocol - oriented language, because of that I am trying to do this using protocol.

Comment: Related: [Operation on an array of structs implementing Equatable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41298464/2976878)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you need to do is to use type erasure, much like `AnyHashable` does in the Swift Standard Library.

You can't do:

```
var a: [Hashable] = [5, "Yo"]
// error: protocol 'Hashable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
```

What you have to do is to use the type-erased type `AnyHashable`:

```
var a: [AnyHashable] = [AnyHashable(5), AnyHashable("Yo")]
a[0].hashValue // => shows 5 in a playground
```

So your solution would be to first split the protocol in smaller parts and promote `Equatable` to `Hashable` (to reuse `AnyHashable`)

```
protocol Conditionable {
    var condition: Condition? { get set }
}

protocol Executable {
    func execute() -> SKAction
}

protocol Commandable: Hashable, Executable, Conditionable {}
```

Then create an `AnyCommandable` struct, like this:

```
struct AnyCommandable: Commandable, Equatable {
    var exeBase: Executable
    var condBase: Conditionable
    var eqBase: AnyHashable

    init<T: Commandable>(_ commandable: T) where T : Equatable {
        self.condBase = commandable
        self.exeBase = commandable
        self.eqBase = AnyHashable(commandable)
    }

    var condition: Condition? {
        get {
            return condBase.condition
        }
        set {
            condBase.condition = condition
        }
    }

    var hashValue: Int {
        return eqBase.hashValue
    }

    func execute() -> SKAction {
        return exeBase.execute()
    }

    public static func ==(lhs: AnyCommandable, rhs: AnyCommandable) -> Bool {
        return lhs.eqBase == rhs.eqBase
    }
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
var a = FunctionCommand()
a.commands = [AnyCommandable(MoveCommand()), AnyCommandable(FunctionCommand())]
```

And you can easily access properties of `commands`, because `AnyCommandable` implements `Commandable`

```
a.commands[0].condition
```

You need to remember to now add `Hashable` and `Equatable` to all your commands.
I used those implementations for testing:

```
struct MoveCommand: Commandable {

    var movingVector: CGVector!

    var condition: Condition?
    func execute() -> SKAction {
        return SKAction()
    }

    var hashValue: Int {
        return Int(movingVector.dx) * Int(movingVector.dy)
    }

    public static func ==(lhs: MoveCommand, rhs: MoveCommand) -> Bool {
        return lhs.movingVector == rhs.movingVector
    }
}

struct FunctionCommand: Commandable {
    var commands = [AnyCommandable]()

    var condition: Condition?

    func execute() -> SKAction {
        return SKAction.group(commands.map { $0.execute() })
    }

    var hashValue: Int {
        return commands.count
    }

    public static func ==(lhs: FunctionCommand, rhs: FunctionCommand) -> Bool {
        return lhs.commands == rhs.commands
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually you probably can merge `exeBase` and `condBase` in one variable, as long as no protocol has used `Self` in any method declaration.

Answer (score 4):

I think it can be easily done by introduction of your own `CustomEquatable` protocol.

```
protocol Commandable: CustomEquatable {
    var condition: String {get}
}

protocol CustomEquatable {
    func isEqual(to: CustomEquatable) -> Bool
}
```

Then, you objects have to conform to this protocol and additionally it should conform Equitable as well.

```
struct MoveCommand: Commandable, Equatable {
    let movingVector: CGRect
    let condition: String

    func isEqual(to: CustomEquatable) -> Bool {
        guard let rhs = to as? MoveCommand else { return false }

        return movingVector == rhs.movingVector && condition == rhs.condition
    }
}

struct RotateCommand: Commandable, Equatable {
    let side: CGFloat
    let condition: String

    func isEqual(to: CustomEquatable) -> Bool {
        guard let rhs = to as? RotateCommand else { return false }

        return side == rhs.side && condition == rhs.condition
    }
}
```

All you need to do now is connect your *CustomEquatable* protocol to Swift *Equatable* through generic extension:

```
extension Equatable where Self: CustomEquatable {

    static func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        return lhs.isEqual(to: rhs)
    }
}
```

It's not a perfect solution, but now, you can store your objects in a array of protocol objects and use **==** operator with your objects as well. For example(I simplified objects a little bit):

```
let move = MoveCommand(movingVector: .zero, condition: "some")
let rotate = RotateCommand(side: 0, condition: "some")

var array = [Commandable]()
array.append(move)
array.append(rotate)  

let equal = (move == MoveCommand(movingVector: .zero, condition: "some"))
let unequal = (move == MoveCommand(movingVector: .zero, condition: "other"))
let unequal = (move == rotate) // can't do this, compare different types
```

PS. Using var on struct is not a good practice, especially for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem here is that the equatable protocol has self requirements. So you can solve you problem by removing equatable protocol from your Commandable protocol and make your your structs equatable instead. This will of course limit your protocol but maybe it is a trade-off that is reasonable?

Comment: If Equatable will be removed from Command, then i can't simply check elements via ==, instead i will need to write switch or if for type checking.

Comment: @BohdanSavych Yes, it is true but what you want is not possible and could not work. What about having a equal method that takes a commandable as a parameter on the protocol? This is a workaround that could maybe satisfy your needs?