# How to evaluate equality for homogeneous collections?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

**The case:**

Consider the following:

```
protocol Car {
    static var country: String { get }
    var id: Int { get }
    var name: String { get set }
}

struct BMW: Car {
    static var country: String = "Germany"
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}

struct Toyota: Car {
    static var country: String = "Japan"
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}
```

Here I have a simple example of how to create an abstraction layer by using a -`Car`- protocol, thus I am able to declare a heterogeneous collection of cars:

```
let cars: [Car] = [BMW(id: 101, name: "X6"), Toyota(id: 102, name: "Prius")]
```

And it works fine.

**The problem:**

I want to be able to evaluate the equality of the cars (by `id`), example:

```
cars[0] != cars[1] // true
```

So, what I tried to do is to let `Car` to conforms to `Equatable` protocol:

```
protocol Car: Equatable { ...
```

However, I got the "typical" compile-time error:

> error: protocol 'Car' can only be used as a generic constraint because
>   it has Self or associated type requirements

I am unable to declare `cars: [Car]` array anymore. If I am not mistaking, the reason behind it is that `Equatable` uses `Self` so it would be considered as homogeneous.

How can I handle this problem? Could [Type erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure) be a mechanism to resolve it?

Comment: Why the country property is a static?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array of protocol type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42046618/array-of-protocol-type)

Comment: @Ahmad F type erasure is exactly what you need

Comment: @BohdanSavych could you mention briefly how type erasure could be a solution for my issue?

Comment: I would consider whether you really need a protocol here – why not make the car manufacturer a property of a single `Car` struct rather than its own type? e.g https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/b2208d647358472e290dcd002658df33

Comment: Appreciate your suggestion @Hamish , it could be even a better approach to follow. I would invite you to add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some good solutions to the general problem have already been given – if you just want a way to compare two `Car` values for equality, then overloading `==` or defining your own equality method, as shown by [@Vyacheslav](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51377819/2976878) and [@vadian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51377584/2976878) respectively, is a quick and simple way to go. However note that this isn't an actual conformance to `Equatable`, and therefore won't compose for example with conditional conformances – i.e you won't be able to then compare two `[Car]` values without defining another equality overload.

The more general solution to the problem, as shown by [@BohdanSavych](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51381221/2976878), is to build a wrapper type that provides the conformance to `Equatable`. This requires more boilerplate, but generally composes better.

It's worth noting that the inability to use protocols with associated types as actual types is just a current limitation of the Swift language – a limitation that will likely be lifted in future versions with [generalised existentials](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#existentials).

However it often helps in situations like this to consider whether your data structures can be reorganised to eliminate the need for a protocol to begin with, which can eliminate the associated complexity. Rather than modelling individual manufacturers as separate types – how about modelling a manufacturer as a type, and then have a property of this type on a single `Car` structure?

For example:

```
struct Car : Hashable {
  struct ID : Hashable {
    let rawValue: Int
  }
  let id: ID

  struct Manufacturer : Hashable {
    var name: String
    var country: String // may want to consider lifting into a "Country" type
  }
  let manufacturer: Manufacturer
  let name: String
}

extension Car.Manufacturer {
  static let bmw = Car.Manufacturer(name: "BMW", country: "Germany")
  static let toyota = Car.Manufacturer(name: "Toyota", country: "Japan")
}

extension Car {
  static let bmwX6 = Car(
    id: ID(rawValue: 101), manufacturer: .bmw, name: "X6"
  )
  static let toyotaPrius = Car(
    id: ID(rawValue: 102), manufacturer: .toyota, name: "Prius"
  )
}

let cars: [Car] = [.bmwX6, .toyotaPrius]
print(cars[0] != cars[1]) // true
```

Here we're taking advantage of the automatic `Hashable` synthesis introduced in [SE-0185](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0185-synthesize-equatable-hashable.md) for Swift 4.1, which will consider all of `Car`'s stored properties for equality. If you want to refine this to only consider the `id`, you can provide your own implementation of `==` and `hashValue` (just be sure to enforce the invariant that if `x.id == y.id`, then all the other properties are equal).

Given that the conformance is so easily synthesised, IMO there's no real reason to just conform to `Equatable` rather than `Hashable` in this case.

A couple of other noteworthy things in the above example:

- Using a `ID` nested structure to represent the `id` property instead of a plain `Int`. It doesn't make sense to perform `Int` operations on such a value (what does it mean to subtract two identifiers?), and you don't want to be able to pass a car identifier to something that for example expects a pizza identifier. By lifting the value into its own strong nested type, we can avoid these issues (Rob Napier has [a great talk that uses this exact example](https://youtu.be/_S6UOrwS-Tg?t=17m15s)).
- Using convenience `static` properties for common values. This lets us for example define the manufacturer BMW once and then re-use the value across different car models that they make.

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution is a protocol extension, instead of an operator it provides an `isEqual(to` function

```
protocol Car {
    static var country: String { get }
    var id: Int { get }
    var name: String { get set }
    func isEqual(to car : Car) -> Bool
}

extension Car {
    func isEqual(to car : Car) -> Bool {
        return self.id == car.id
    }
}
```

and use it

```
cars[0].isEqual(to: cars[1])
```

Comment: Actually, that's the only way that I could though about, but do you think that there is a way to achieve it via the `==`? or it won't be possible?

Comment: Please see Vyacheslav's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution using *Type Erasure*:

```
protocol Car {
    var id: Int { get }
    var name: String { get set }
}

struct BMW: Car {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}

struct Toyota: Car {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}

struct AnyCar: Car, Equatable {
    private var carBase: Car

    init(_ car: Car) {
        self.carBase = car
    }

    var id: Int { return self.carBase.id }
    var name: String {
        get { return carBase.name}
        set { carBase.name = newValue }
    }

    public static func ==(lhs: AnyCar, rhs: AnyCar) -> Bool {
        return lhs.carBase.id == rhs.carBase.id
    }
}



let cars: [AnyCar] = [AnyCar(BMW(id: 101, name: "X6")), AnyCar(Toyota(id: 101, name: "Prius"))]

print(cars[0] == cars[1])
```

<sub>Don't know how to implement this with static property. If I figure out, I will edit this answer.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to override `==`:

```
import UIKit

var str = "Hello, playground"
protocol Car {
    static var country: String { get }
    var id: Int { get }
    var name: String { get set }
}

struct BMW: Car {
    static var country: String = "Germany"
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}

struct Toyota: Car {
    static var country: String = "Japan"
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}

func ==(lhs: Car, rhs: Car) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id
}

BMW(id:0, name:"bmw") == Toyota(id: 0, name: "toyota")
```