# Using diff in an array of objects that conform to a protocol

Tags: swift, lcs

I'm experimenting with using Composition instead of Inheritance and I wanted to use `diff` on an array of objects that comply with a given protocol.

To do so, I implemented a protocol and made it comply with `Equatable`:

```
// Playground - noun: a place where people can play
import XCPlayground
import Foundation

protocol Field:Equatable {
    var content: String { get }
}

func ==<T: Field>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool {
    return lhs.content == rhs.content
}

func ==<T: Field, U: Field>(lhs: T, rhs: U) -> Bool {
    return lhs.content == rhs.content
}

struct First:Field {
    let content:String
}

struct Second:Field {
    let content:String
}

let items:[Field] = [First(content: "abc"), Second(content: "cxz")] //  boom
```

But I've soon discovered that:

> error: protocol 'Field' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

I understand why since Swift is a type-safe language that needs to be able to know the concrete type of these objects at anytime.

After tinkering around, I ended up removing Equatable from the protocol and overloading the `==` operator:

```
// Playground - noun: a place where people can play
import XCPlayground
import Foundation

protocol Field {
    var content: String { get }
}

func ==(lhs: Field, rhs: Field) -> Bool {
    return lhs.content == rhs.content
}

func ==(lhs: [Field], rhs: [Field]) -> Bool {
    return (lhs.count == rhs.count) && (zip(lhs, rhs).map(==).reduce(true, { $0 && $1 })) // naive, but let's go with it for the sake of the argument
}

struct First:Field {
    let content:String
}

struct Second:Field {
    let content:String
}


// Requirement #1: direct object comparison
print(First(content: "abc") == First(content: "abc")) // true
print(First(content: "abc") == Second(content: "abc")) // false

// Requirement #2: being able to diff an array of objects complying with the Field protocol
let array1:[Field] = [First(content: "abc"), Second(content: "abc")]
let array2:[Field] = [Second(content: "abc")]

print(array1 == array2) // false
let outcome = array1.diff(array2) //  boom
```

> error: value of type '[Field]' has no member 'diff'

From here on, I'm a bit lost to be honest. I read some great posts about type erasure but even the provided examples suffered from the same issue (which I assume is the lack of conformance to `Equatable`).

Am I right? And if so, how can this be done?

**UPDATE**:
I had to stop this experiment for a while and totally forgot about a dependency, sorry! `Diff` is a method provided by [SwiftLCS](https://github.com/Frugghi/SwiftLCS), an implementation of the longest common subsequence (LCS) algorithm.

**TL;DR:**
The `Field` protocol needs to comply with `Equatable` but so far I have not been able to do this. I need to be able to create an array of objects that comply to this protocol (see the error in the first code block).

Thanks again

Comment: It's impossible to say without knowing what `diff` is, but I have a feeling [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41298464/2976878) will be relevant. Assuming `diff` is some method which depends on the elements being `Equatable`, another alternative would be to implement an overload for it that takes a custom predicate in order to do the equality check. You can pass in your custom equality overload in that case.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! Diff is a method provided by SwiftLCS (https://github.com/Frugghi/SwiftLCS). I started this experiment a month ago but had to stop and completely forgot about this dependency... I've added it to my playground and you're right, it really requires Equatable.

Comment: Did you see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41300843/2976878) to the linked Q&A? A type-erased wrapper for `AnyField` would solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from a combination of the meaning of the `Equatable` protocol and Swift’s support for type overloaded functions.

Let’s take a look at the `Equatable` protocol:

```
protocol Equatable
{
    static func ==(Self, Self) -> Bool
}
```

What does this mean? Well it’s important to understand what “equatable” actually means in the context of Swift. “Equatable” is a trait of a structure or class that make it so that any *instance* of that structure or class can be compared for equality with any other *instance* of that structure or class. It says nothing about comparing it for equality with an instance of a different class or structure.

Think about it. `Int` and `String` are both types that are `Equatable`. `13 == 13` and `"meredith" == "meredith"`. But does `13 == "meredith"`?

The `Equatable` protocol only cares about when both things to be compared are of the same type. It says nothing about what happens when the two things are of different types. That’s why both arguments in the definition of `==(::)` are of type `Self`.

Let’s look at what happened in your example.

```
protocol Field:Equatable 
{
    var content:String { get }
}

func ==<T:Field>(lhs:T, rhs:T) -> Bool 
{
    return lhs.content == rhs.content
}

func ==<T:Field, U:Field>(lhs:T, rhs:U) -> Bool 
{
    return lhs.content == rhs.content
}
```

You provided two overloads for the `==` operator. But only the first one has to do with `Equatable` conformance. The second overload is the one that gets applied when you do

```
First(content: "abc") == Second(content: "abc")
```

which has nothing to do with the `Equatable` protocol.

Here’s a point of confusion. Equability across instances of the *same* type is a *lower* requirement than equability across instances of *different* types when we’re talking about individually bound instances of types you want to test for equality. (Since we can assume both things being tested are of the same type.)

However, when we make an array of things that conform to `Equatable`, this is a *higher* requirement than making an array of things that can be tested for equality, since what you are saying is that *every item in the array can be compared **as if they were both of the same type***. But since your structs are of different types, you can’t guarantee this, and so the code fails to compile.

Here’s another way to think of it.

Protocols without associated type requirements, and protocols with associated type requirements are really two different animals. Protocols without `Self` basically look and behave like types. Protocols with `Self` are traits that *types themselves conform to*. In essence, they go “up a level”, like a type of type. (Related in concept to **metatypes**.)

That’s why it makes no sense to write something like this:

```
let array:[Equatable] = [5, "a", false]
```

You can write this:

```
let array:[Int] = [5, 6, 7]
```

or this:

```
let array:[String] = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

or this:

```
let array:[Bool] = [false, true, false]
```

Because `Int`, `String`, and `Bool` are types. `Equatable` isn’t a type, it’s a type of a type.

It *would* make “sense” to write something like this…

```
let array:[Equatable] = [Int.self, String.self, Bool.self]
```

though this is really stretching the bounds of type-safe programming and so Swift doesn’t allow this. You’d need a fully flexible metatyping system like Python’s to express an idea like that.

So how do we solve your problem? Well, first of all realize that the only reason it makes sense to apply SwiftLCS on your array is because, at some level, all of your array elements can be reduced to an array of keys that are all of the same `Equatable` type. In this case, it’s `String`, since you can get an array `keys:[String]` by doing `[Field](...).map{ $0.content }`. Perhaps if we redesigned SwiftLCS, this would make a better interface for it.

However, since we can only compare our array of `Field`s directly, we need to make sure they can all be upcast to the same type, and the way to do that is with inheritance.

```
class Field:Equatable
{
    let content:String

    static func == (lhs:Field, rhs:Field) -> Bool
    {
        return lhs.content == rhs.content
    }

    init(_ content:String)
    {
        self.content = content
    }
}

class First:Field
{
    init(content:String)
    {
        super.init(content)
    }
}

class Second:Field
{
    init(content:String)
    {
        super.init(content)
    }
}


let items:[Field] = [First(content: "abc"), Second(content: "cxz")]
```

The array then upcasts them all to type `Field` which is `Equatable`.

By the way, ironically, the “protocol-oriented” solution to this problem actually still involves inheritance. The SwiftLCS API would provide a protocol like

```
protocol LCSElement 
{
    associatedtype Key:Equatable
    var key:Key { get }
}
```

We would specialize it with a superclass

```
class Field:LCSElement
{
    let key:String // <- this is what specializes Key to a concrete type

    static func == (lhs:Field, rhs:Field) -> Bool
    {
        return lhs.key == rhs.key
    }

    init(_ key:String)
    {
        self.key = key
    }
}
```

and the library would use it as

```
func LCS<T: LCSElement>(array:[T])
{
    array[0].key == array[1].key
    ...
}
```

Protocols and Inheritance are not opposites or substitutes for one another. They complement each other.

Comment: Taylor, am I right that this approach means OP can't use existing  SwiftLCS library and has to roll out his own? Also what to do if the list is not homogeneous even by key? I mean what if `Field` is really a "`Variant`" and subclasses represent each concrete type such as string, date, number, etc. It still might make sense to find a difference between two arrays of such `Field`s. If you see how to work around those limitations, I'm interested in seeing that.

Comment: @SergGr the superclass approach (without the `LCSElement` protocol) will work with the existing SwiftLCS library. If the array is not homogenous even by key (or hash) it’s hard to see how equality tests can satisfy transitivity since you’d need consistent definitions for testing every possible combination of items in the array.

Comment: `Equatable` defines just `==` so what's the problem with transitivity? In my example with Variant type, obviously values of different specific types are never equal, and values inside the same specific type are compared according to that type's rules. I don't see how this can lead to any issues with transitivity. If `a == b` and `b == c` then all 3 are of the same specific type and thus you can compare `a` and `c` by the type-specific rules and they can easily be transitive.

Comment: @SergGr it may satisfy `Equatable` but all bets are off as to whether the actual algorithm that uses it will work right. Also, if `a:String == b:Int` and `b:Int == c:Float`, how do we guarantee that `a:String == c:Float`? I can define `==(:String:Int) and ==(:Int:Float)` to always return `true`, and define `==(:String:Float)` to always return `false`. That’s not good! The only way this works is if we hash them all to the same type.

Comment: Taylor, if you have some real-world business rule that somehow says that some `a:String == b:Int` I don't see problems exending it to cover `a:String == c:Float` in a transitive way. But a simpler (and IMHO closer to real life) approach is as I mentioned to just say that values of different "inner" types are never equal.

Comment: @SergGr for the `Variant` you’re describing, I think this is beyond the capabilities of protocols…you are probably better off using an array of `[Any]`s and testing for type equality and value equality separately, inside the library… clearly this is beyond what the SwiftLCS library was ever designed to do, but `[Any]` is the Swiftie go-to for anything ‘heterogenous-y’.

Comment: @taylorswift Thanks for taking the time to provide such a detailed answer, quite insightful. I particularly agree with "Protocols and Inheritance are not opposites or substitutes for one another. They complement each other".

Comment: @taylorswift Still, this is just an experiment. I wanted to know if it could be done without resorting to inheritance. As such, I'll accept SergGr's answer. I wish I could I accept both, to be honest. Thank you for your effort

Comment: Actually, I think we can find some middle ground and award reputation points all round. @SergGr you'll get the bounty because your solution effectively solves my problem. taylorswift, I'll accept your answer because theoretically it really doesn't make much sense to do this the way I wanted to. Hope everyone is happy, I feel this is fairer

Answer (score 1):

I know this is probably now what you want but the only way I know how to make it work is to introduce additional wrapper class:

```
struct FieldEquatableWrapper: Equatable {
    let wrapped: Field

    public static func ==(lhs: FieldEquatableWrapper, rhs: FieldEquatableWrapper) -> Bool {
        return lhs.wrapped.content == rhs.wrapped.content
    }

    public static func diff(_ coll: [Field], _ otherCollection: [Field]) -> Diff<Int> {
        let w1 = coll.map({ FieldEquatableWrapper(wrapped: $0) })
        let w2 = otherCollection.map({ FieldEquatableWrapper(wrapped: $0) })
        return w1.diff(w2)
    }
}
```

and then you can do

```
    let outcome = FieldEquatableWrapper.diff(array1, array2)
```

I don't think you can make `Field` to conform to `Equatable` at all as it is designed to be "type-safe" using `Self` pseudo-class. And this is one reason for the wrapper class. Unfortunately there seems to be one more issue that I don't know how to fix: I can't put this "wrapped" `diff` into `Collection` or `Array` extension and still make it support heterogenous `[Field]` array without compilation error:

> using 'Field' as a concrete type conforming to protocol 'Field' is not supported

If anyone knows a better solution, I'm interested as well.

P.S.

In the question you mention that

```
print(First(content: "abc") == Second(content: "abc")) // false
```

but I expect that to be `true` given the way you defined your `==` operator

Comment: I understand. Still, some quick considerations: a) I don't need to implement the diff function itself, the other lib provides it and b) I'm getting a "protocol 'Field' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements" error when declaring the wrapper variable

Comment: @JoãoPereira, my code requires `Field` to **_not_** extend `Equatable`. As I said I don't think you can make `Field` extend `Equatable` and still make code work.  As for "I don't need to implement the `diff` function itself", I don't implement it, `FieldEquatableWrapper` delegates call to the library but first it wraps arguments of array type `[Field]` into array `[FieldEquatableWrapper]`. You can add similar delegating wrapper-methods for any other method of that library that you need.