# No associated type, and yet: Protocol can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, associated-types

Even though I have no `associated type`, I get this error:

> Protocol can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

The code is as follows. I define a `protocol` called `Board`, and then, within another `protocol` (called `Rules`) I create a parameter of type `Board`. That's when I get the error.

I have **no associated type**, so I don't know what the compiler is talking about...

```
protocol Board : Equatable, Hashable  {
    init()

    var width  : Int {get}
    var height : Int {get}

}

protocol Rules {
    init(board: Board)
}
```

What on Earth am I doing wrong???

Comment: Take a look at `Equatable`'s definition ;)

Comment: @Hamish OK, I see the Sekf there. What's the best way to solve this? Could elaborate on this whole issue as a response? I'll accept it right away. Thanks!

Comment: As the error message suggests, you could use a generic initialiser, e.g `init<T : Board>(board: T)`

Comment: OK, that gets rid of the error, although I'm not sure what on Earth is going on... I'll check the video from Alex Gallager that was recommended elsewhere.

Comment: It's [merely a language limitation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41695792/2976878) – you currently cannot directly talk in terms of heterogeneous types that conform to a given protocol with associated type(s), as the compiler won't know what the concrete type(s) are for those associated type(s). See also [this related Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41298464/2976878) for the specific case of needing to talk about heterogeneous types that conform to `Equatable`.