# Checking Hashable conformance

Tags: swift, generics

I have a base protocol (Model) that some structs conform to. They also conform to Hashable

```
protocol Model {}
struct Contact: Model, Hashable {
    var hashValue: Int { return ... }
    static func ==(lhs: Contact, rhs: Contact) -> Bool { return ... } 
}
struct Address: Model, Hashable {
    var hashValue: Int { return ... }
    static func ==(lhs: Address, rhs: Address) -> Bool { return ... } 
}
```

I have a function that takes an array of objects conforming to Model ([Model]).
How can I pass the [Model] to a function that requires Hashables without making Model Hashable?

```
func complete(with models: [Model]) {
    doSomethingWithHashable(models) //can't do this
}
func doSomethingWithHashable <T:Hashable>(_ objects: [T]) {
    //
}
```

I'm trying to avoid this

```
protocol Model: Hashable {}
func complete<T:Model>(with models: [T]) {
    runComparison(models)
}
```

Because I get "Model cannot be used as a generic constraint..." when I do this

```
protocol SomethingElse {
    var data: [Model] { get }
}
```

Comment: What if there is another type which conforms to `Model`, but not to `Hashable`?

Comment: I don't have that scenario

Comment: Somewhat related: [Operation on an array of structs implementing Equatable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41298464/2976878) – you could build an `AnyHashableModel` type-erased wrapper in a similar way to `AnyVehicle` in that Q&A (the main difference being simply storing an extra function for the `hashValue` getting).

Comment: That should do it. Can you make your comment into an answer please?

Comment: @joels Sure thing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you're talking in terms of `Model`, which promises *nothing* about `Hashable` conformance. As you point out, the problem with telling the compiler about this (i.e deriving `Model` from `Hashable`) is you then lose the ability to talk in terms of heterogenous types that conform to `Model`.

If you don't even care about `Model` conformance in the first place, you can just use the standard library's [`AnyHashable`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/anyhashable) type-erased wrapper for *completely arbitrary* `Hashable` conforming instances.

However, assuming you do care about `Model` conformance, you'll have to build your own [type-erased wrapper](http://robnapier.net/erasure) for instances that conform to both `Model` and `Hashable`. In [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41300843/2976878), I demonstrate how a type eraser can be built for `Equatable` conforming types. The logic there can be very easily extended for `Hashable` – we just need to store an extra function to return the `hashValue` of the instance.

For example:

```
struct AnyHashableModel : Model, Hashable {

    static func ==(lhs: AnyHashableModel, rhs: AnyHashableModel) -> Bool {

        // forward to both lhs's and rhs's _isEqual in order to determine equality.
        // the reason that both must be called is to preserve symmetry for when a
        // superclass is being compared with a subclass.
        // if you know you're always working with value types, you can omit one of them.
        return lhs._isEqual(rhs) || rhs._isEqual(lhs)
    }

    private let base: Model

    private let _isEqual: (_ to: AnyHashableModel) -> Bool
    private let _hashValue: () -> Int

    init<T : Model>(_ base: T) where T : Hashable {

        self.base = base

        _isEqual = {
            // attempt to cast the passed instance to the concrete type that
            // AnyHashableModel was initialised with, returning the result of that
            // type's == implementation, or false otherwise.
            if let other = $0.base as? T {
                return base == other
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }

        // simply assign a closure that captures base and returns its hashValue
        _hashValue = { base.hashValue }
    }

    var hashValue: Int { return _hashValue() }
}
```

You would then use it like so:

```
func complete(with models: [AnyHashableModel]) {
    doSomethingWithHashable(models)
}

func doSomethingWithHashable<T : Hashable>(_ objects: [T]) {
    //
}

let models = [AnyHashableModel(Contact()), AnyHashableModel(Address())]
complete(with: models)
```

Here I'm assuming that you'll also want to use it as a wrapper for `Model`'s requirements (assuming there are some). Alternatively, you can expose the `base` property and remove the `Model` conformance from `AnyHashableModel` itself, making callers access the `base` for the underlying `Model` conforming instance:

```
struct AnyHashableModel : Hashable {
    // ...
    let base: Model
    // ...
}
```

---

You will however note that the above type-erased wrapper is only applicable to types that are both `Hashable` and a `Model`. What if we want to talk about some other protocol where the conforming instances are `Hashable`?

A more general solution, as I demonstrate [in this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41976844/2976878), is to instead accept types that are both `Hashable` and conform to some other protocol – the type of which is expressed by a generic placeholder.

As there's currently no way in Swift to express a generic placeholder that must conform to a protocol given by another generic placeholder; this relationship must be defined by the caller with a `transform` closure to perform the necessary upcast. However, thanks to Swift 3.1's acceptance of concrete same-type requirements in extensions, we can define a convenience initialiser to remove this boilerplate for `Model` (and this can be repeated for other protocol types).

For example:

```
/// Type-erased wrapper for a type that conforms to Hashable,
/// but inherits from/conforms to a type T that doesn't necessarily require
/// Hashable conformance. In almost all cases, T should be a protocol type.
struct AnySpecificHashable<T> : Hashable {

    static func ==(lhs: AnySpecificHashable, rhs: AnySpecificHashable) -> Bool {
        return lhs._isEqual(rhs) || rhs._isEqual(lhs)
    }

    let base: T

    private let _isEqual: (_ to: AnySpecificHashable) -> Bool
    private let _hashValue: () -> Int

    init<U : Hashable>(_ base: U, upcast: (U) -> T) {

        self.base = upcast(base)

        _isEqual = {
            if let other = $0.base as? U {
                return base == other
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }

        _hashValue = { base.hashValue }
    }
    var hashValue: Int { return _hashValue() }
}

// extension for convenience initialiser for when T is Model.
extension AnySpecificHashable where T == Model {
    init<U : Model>(_ base: U) where U : Hashable {
        self.init(base, upcast: { $0 })
    }
}
```

You would now want to wrap your instances in a `AnySpecificHashable<Model>`:

```
func complete(with models: [AnySpecificHashable<Model>]) {
    doSomethingWithHashable(models)
}

func doSomethingWithHashable<T : Hashable>(_ objects: [T]) {
    //
}

let models: [AnySpecificHashable<Model>] = [
    AnySpecificHashable(Contact()),
    AnySpecificHashable(Address())
]

complete(with: models)
```