# Swift Declare a protocol equatable

Tags: swift

I have a protocol:

```
protocol CustomProtocol {
   var title: String { get }
   var subtitle: String { get }
}
```

Then i have 2 objects, that conform this procotol. And i want to compare them, so i would like to CustomProtocol to be Equatable.

```
protocol CustomProtocol: Equatable {
   var title: String { get }
   var subtitle: String { get }
    static func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
}

extension CustomProtocol {
    static func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        return lhs.title == rhs.title
    }
}
```

But after that change i get "Protocol CustomProtocol can only be used  as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requeriments.
The only way i can think to solve this is to have a third property like a hash that depends on the others and compare this property.

[image]

[Here you have a sample](http://www.ruiznadal.com/playground.zip) playground with the actual code.

Comment: You need to remove the equality functions from your updated protocol declaration as they're only needed in the extension.

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/41298464/2976878

Answer (score 3):

Because `Equatable` has `Self` requirements, it should not be implemented directly on a protocol. Otherwise, the protocol will be unusable as a type.

To implement `Equatable` at the protocol level yet be able to use the protocol as a type, you can use type erasure.

To demonstrate, I have modified the code given in your playground to build a type eraser.

For a detailed explanation of the approach I have used, check out this post on my blog:

https://khawerkhaliq.com/blog/swift-protocols-equatable-part-two/

Here is the modified code from your playground:

```
protocol CustomProtocol {
    var title: String { get }
    var subtitle: String { get }
    func isEqualTo(_ other: CustomProtocol) -> Bool
    func asEquatable() -> AnyEquatableCustomProtocol
}

extension CustomProtocol where Self: Equatable {
    func isEqualTo(_ other: CustomProtocol) -> Bool {
        guard let o = other as? Self else { return false }
        return self == o
    }
    func asEquatable() -> AnyEquatableCustomProtocol {
        return AnyEquatableCustomProtocol(self)
    }
}

struct A: CustomProtocol, Equatable {
    var title: String
    var subtitle: String
    static func ==(lhs: A, rhs: A) -> Bool {
        return lhs.title == rhs.title && lhs.subtitle == rhs.subtitle
    }
}

struct B: CustomProtocol, Equatable {
    var title: String
    var subtitle: String
    static func ==(lhs: B, rhs: B) -> Bool {
        return lhs.title == rhs.title && lhs.subtitle == rhs.subtitle
    }
}

struct AnyEquatableCustomProtocol: CustomProtocol, Equatable {
    var title: String { return value.title }
    var subtitle: String { return value.subtitle }
    init(_ value: CustomProtocol) { self.value = value }
    private let value: CustomProtocol
    static func ==(lhs: AnyEquatableCustomProtocol, rhs: AnyEquatableCustomProtocol) -> Bool {
        return lhs.value.isEqualTo(rhs.value)
    }
}

// instances typed as the protocol
let a: CustomProtocol = A(title: "First title", subtitle: "First subtitle")
let b: CustomProtocol = B(title: "First title", subtitle: "First subtitle")
let equalA: CustomProtocol = A(title: "First title", subtitle: "First subtitle")
let unequalA: CustomProtocol = A(title: "Second title", subtitle: "Second subtitle")

// equality tests
print(a.asEquatable() == b.asEquatable())           // prints false
print(a.asEquatable() == equalA.asEquatable())      // prints true
print(a.asEquatable() == unequalA.asEquatable())    // prints false
```

The point to note is that with this approach the actual `==` comparisons are delegated to the underlying concrete types, yet we deal only with protocol types to maintain abstraction.

Here I have used the type erased instances only for one comparison. However, since the type eraser conforms to `CustomProtocol` these instances can be saved and used in any place where a protocol type is expected. Because they conform to `Equatable`, they can also be used in any place where `Equatable` conformance is required.

Just for context, this post explains why it is not advisable to try to implement `Equatable` conformance or even `==` functions directly on protocols:

https://khawerkhaliq.com/blog/swift-protocols-equatable-part-one/

Hence the type erasure.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The Equatable protocol has a self constraint to solve the problem that you only should be able to check equality between objects of the same type, not the same protocol. That's why it has a self-requirement. Otherwise you could just say

```
let a: Equatable = 42
let b: Equatable = "hello"
```

and `a == b` would work. This would be bad because you could compare objects of totally unrelated types. The self-requirement makes this a compile time error.

If you want to compare your objects on a protocol basis, just implement the `==` operator without a self-requirement:

```
extension CustomProtocol {
    func == (lhs: CustomProtocol, rhs: CustomProtocol) -> Bool {
         return lhs.name == rhs.name
    }
    func != (lhs: CustomProtocol, rhs: CustomProtocol) -> Bool {
         return !(lhs == rhs)
    }
}
```

Now you can declare instances of your protocol directly with the `CustomProtocol` type and compare them.

But maybe the protocol is not the right abstraction in this case. Maybe you should implement this as an abstract class.

Comment: I get 'Ambiguous reference to =='

Comment: Of course your protocol can no longer inherit from `Equatable`.

Comment: I added a sample Playground, the same after removing the inherit.

Comment: You can try to put the `==` and `!=` function into global scope instead of an extension.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the rhs parameter is not the same type of the lhs. They just conform to the same protocol.

You could solve that by using a generic type as the second parameter.

```swift
exension CustomProtocol {
    static func ==<T: CustomProtocol>(lhs: Self, rhs: T) -> Bool {
        return lhs.title == rhs.title
    }
}
```