# Swift protocol extension where Self: Equatable doesn't work

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

Can anyone shed a light as to why this doesn't work? I get an error `Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Self' and 'CustomEquatable'`

```
protocol CustomEquatable {
    func isEqualTo(_ other: CustomEquatable) -> Bool
}

extension CustomEquatable where Self: Equatable {
    func isEqualTo(_ other: CustomEquatable) -> Bool {
        return self == other
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is that just because `self` is equatable, and `other` is a `CustomEquatable` (which implies that it too is `Equatable`), that doesn't mean that the type of `self` is the same as the type of `other`. For example, if both `Int` and `String` were extended to conform to `CustomEquatable`, then `1.isEqualTo("a")` would call `1 == "a"`, which does not type check, because `==` requires LHS and RHS to have the same type.

Comment: To provide a solution, we would need to know what you're trying to achieve with this `CustomEquatable` protocol. Is this your attempt to try and resolve the dreaded "protocol 'Equatable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements" error?

Comment: @Alexander yes, yes I am.

Comment: Here's a proper implementation of an `AnyEquatable` type eraser: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46288607/3141234

Comment: The trick is that the initializer is generic, but the type is not.

Comment: @Alexander: *"other is a CustomEquatable (which implies that it too is Equatable)"* – Unless I am mistaken, `other` can be  a *different* type adopting CustomEquatable, and need not be Equatable.

Comment: @MartinR Oh yes, indeed, you're correct. It just won't have this default impl provided, but that's irrelevant. My reasoning thereafter is correct, however. The type of `self` and `other` will differ, leading to an illegal call of `==`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with your `CustomEquatable` protocol, **without** the extension:

> ```
> protocol CustomEquatable {
>     func isEqualTo(_ other: CustomEquatable) -> Bool
> }
> ```

Let's define some types to use for experiments:

```
struct A: Equatable {
    let name: String
}

struct B: Equatable {
    let id: Int
}
```

Suppose we then want `A` and `B` to conform to `CustomEquatable`. Then we have four cases to consider:

- What does `a1.isEqualTo(a2)` mean (where `a1` and `a2` are both of type `A`)?
- What does `b1.isEqualTo(b2)` mean (where `b1` and `b2` are both of type `B`)?
- What does `a.isEqualTo(b)` mean (where `a` is an `A` and `b` is a `B`)?
- What does `b.isEqualTo(a)` mean (where `b` is a `B` and `a` is an `A`)?

For the first two cases, possible answers are that `a1.isEqualTo(a2)` if and only if `a1 == a2` and `b1.isEqualTo(b2)` if and only if `b1 == b2`.

For the second two cases, we have to decide if there's a way for an `A` to equal a `B`. The simplest solution (I think) is that an `A` can never equal a `B`.

So we can write the conformances like this:

```
extension A: CustomEquatable {
    func isEqualTo(_ other: CustomEquatable) -> Bool {
        return (other as? A) == self
    }
}

extension B: CustomEquatable {
    func isEqualTo(_ other: CustomEquatable) -> Bool {
        return (other as? B) == self
    }
}
```

The only difference in these two conformances is the cast-to type (on the right side of `as?`). So we can factor out the conformances into a protocol extension like this:

```
extension CustomEquatable where Self: Equatable {
    func isEqualTo(_ other: CustomEquatable) -> Bool {
        return (other as? Self) == self
    }
}
```

With this protocol extension, we can make `A` and `B` conform to `CustomEquatable` without implementing `isEqualTo` for each:

```
extension A: CustomEquatable { }
extension B: CustomEquatable { }
```

To test the code:

```
let a1 = A(name: "a1")
let a2 = A(name: "a2")
let b1 = B(id: 1)
let b2 = B(id: 2)

a1.isEqualTo(a1) // true
a1.isEqualTo(a2) // false
b1.isEqualTo(b1) // true
b1.isEqualTo(b2) // false
a1.isEqualTo(b1) // false
b1.isEqualTo(a1) // false
```

Answer (score 1):

Please watch [WWDC 2015 Protocol-Oriented Programming in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/408/) from 37:25

This is almost literally taken from the video. You have to conditional downcast `other` to `Self`.
If it's the same type you can use `==` otherwise both objects are not equal anyway.

```
protocol CustomEquatable {
    func isEqualTo(_ other: CustomEquatable) -> Bool
}
extension CustomEquatable where Self: Equatable {
    func isEqualTo(_ other: CustomEquatable) -> Bool {
        if let other = other as? Self { return self == other }
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that does explain it very nicely!