# class AnyComparable inherits from class AnyEquatable

Tags: swift, inheritance, initialization

```
public class AnyEquatable: Equatable {
    public let value: Any
    private let equals: (Any) -> Bool

    public init<E: Equatable>(_ value: E) {
        self.value = value
        self.equals = { $0 as? E == value }
    }

    public static func == (lhs: AnyEquatable, rhs: AnyEquatable) -> Bool {
        lhs.equals(rhs.value) || rhs.equals(lhs.value)
    }
}

public class AnyComparable: AnyEquatable, Comparable {
    private let compares: (Any) -> Bool

    public init<C: Comparable>(_ value: C) {
        super.init(value)
        self.compares = { ($0 as? C).map { $0 < value } ?? false }
    }

    public static func < (lhs: AnyComparable, rhs: AnyComparable) -> Bool {
        lhs.compares(rhs.value) || rhs.compares(lhs.value)
    }
}
```

I've got an error:

> Overridden method 'init' has generic signature C where C:
> Comparable which is incompatible with base method's generic signature
> E where E: Equatable; expected generic signature to be C where C:
> Equatable

Why does the compiler think that I'm overriding initializer? I didn't use the word "override". I can't override here because the method 'init' has different signature (which the compiler tells itself). It's not an overriding. I want the subclass to use its own initilizer, and I (obviously) don't want inherit superclass initializer.
So, how can I achieve that? What can be more natural than something comparable inherits from something equatable! Why can't I do that?

Comment: @LeoDabus The main idea I've taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46288607/2167345

Comment: try not subclassing AnyEquatable. `class AnyComparable: Comparable & Equatable {`

Comment: Btw how do you expect to sort different types? And why do you need to check different types if they are equal?

Comment: The init in the derived class is actually an override. The signatures are "incompatible", because if it would be allowed it would violate the "Liskov substitution principle".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your initialiser in the subclass ***does*** override the initialiser in the superclass. If you fix the constraint on `C` as the compiler asks you to, the next thing the compiler will tell you, is that you are missing an `override` keyword.

This behaviour is quite consistent, so it seems like it is deliberately designed that the generic constraints are not taken into account when determining whether one method overrides another. Here's another example of this:

```
class A {
    func f<T>(t: T) {}
}

class B: A {
    func f<C: Equatable>(t: C) {} // error
}
```

Anyway, one way you can work around this is to just change the argument label:

```
public init<C: Comparable>(comparable value: C) {
    self.compares = { ($0 as? C).map { $0 < value } ?? false }
    super.init(value)
}
```

The downside of this is that the client code gets a bit less concise. You have to do `AnyComparable(comparable: something)` every time, which is quite long. One solution is to put both `AnyEquatable` and `AnyComparable` in the same file, make both initialisers `fileprivate`. You can then provide factory functions (in the same file) that create these classes. For example:

```
public extension Equatable {
    func toAnyEquatable() -> AnyEquatable {
        .init(equatable: self)
    }
}

public extension Comparable {
    func toAnyComparable() -> AnyComparable {
        .init(comparable: self)
    }
}
```

Also note that your implementation of `<` doesn't make much sense. It should be:

```
public static func < (lhs: AnyComparable, rhs: AnyComparable) -> Bool {
    lhs.compares(rhs.value) || (rhs != lhs && !rhs.compares(lhs.value))
}
```

and `compares` should mean "less than",

```
self.compares = { ($0 as? C).map { value < $0 } ?? false }
```

to say "lhs < rhs or rhs > lhs".

But even still, there are cases where using this class with completely unrelated types still doesn't make much sense, just FYI:

```
let a = AnyComparable(comparable: "foo")
let b = AnyComparable(comparable: 1)
print(a < b) // true
print(a > b) // true
print(a <= b) // false
print(a >= b) // false
print(a == b) // false
```

So please do be careful!