# Key path value type 'Int' cannot be converted to contextual type 'String'

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift-keypath

I am trying to pass a multiple tuples containing a KeyPath and a type of a sort order to a method that should do sorting.

I have this method:

```
extension Array {
    mutating func sort<T: Comparable>(by criteria: (path: KeyPath<Element, T>, order:OrderType)...) {
        
        criteria.forEach { path, order in
            //...
            sort { first, second in
            order.makeComparator()(
                first[keyPath: path],
                second[keyPath: path]
            )
        }
        }
    }
}
```

and I am using it like this:

```
var posts = BlogPost.examples
        
posts.sort(by:(path:\.pageViews, order: .asc), (path:\.sessionDuration, order: .desc))
```

Now, cause both `pageViews` and `sessionDuration` properties are `integers`, this will work.

But if I want to pass two properties of different types (say `String` and `Int`), I am getting this error:

```
Key path value type 'Int' cannot be converted to contextual type 'String'
```

Here is rest of the code, but I guess is not that relevant:

```
enum OrderType: String {
    case asc
    case desc
}

extension OrderType {
    func makeComparator<T: Comparable>() -> (T, T) -> Bool {
        switch self {
        case .asc:
            return (<)
        case .desc:
            return (>)
        }
    }
}
```

How should I define sort method so that I it accept *heterogenous* key paths?

Comment: There are no variadic generics (yet), so you'll need to write a `AnyComparable` type eraser. See the one I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68878549/class-anycomparable-inherits-from-class-anyequatable/68878884#68878884) for more info.

Comment: Not quite related to your question, but I don't think your implementation of `sort` is quite right... Wouldn't that just be equivalent to sorting by the last key path?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, it only sorts the last parameter for now. I just copied  as it is right now, but yeah, not related to a current problem. Cause I can't even pass what I want to pass :)

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks, `AnyComparable` did the trick.

Comment: Actually I just realised I have made a mistake in that answer. It is fixed now. I think I'll still post an answer here, since the `AnyComparable` there can be adapted quite a lot to fit your needs here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift 5.9, you can write such a method using parameter packs. Here I implemented the sorting using the built-in `KeyPathComparator`:

```
extension Array {
    mutating func sort<each T: Comparable>(by keyPaths: repeat (KeyPath<Element, each T>, SortOrder)) {
        var comparators: [KeyPathComparator<Element>] = []
        func addComparator<Key: Comparable>(_ keyPathOrder: (KeyPath<Element, Key>, SortOrder)) {
            comparators.append(KeyPathComparator(keyPathOrder.0, order: keyPathOrder.1))
        }
        // here I am technically creating a tuple, with its elements all being addComparator calls
        // this could be written more readably when we can iterate over a parameter pack with a for loop
        (repeat addComparator(each keyPaths))
        sort(using: comparators)
    }
}
```

Example Usage:

```
// order by length of string ascendingly, then by the string itself descendingly
someStrings.sort(by: (\.count, .forward), (\.self, .reverse))
```

---

Pre Swift 5.9, you'll need to write a `AnyComparable` type eraser. This one is adapted from this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68878549/class-anycomparable-inherits-from-class-anyequatable/68878884#68878884).

```
struct AnyComparable: Equatable, Comparable {
    private let lessThan: (Any) -> Bool
    private let value: Any
    private let equals: (Any) -> Bool

    public static func == (lhs: AnyComparable, rhs: AnyComparable) -> Bool {
        lhs.equals(rhs.value) || rhs.equals(lhs.value)
    }
    
    public init<C: Comparable>(_ value: C) {
        self.value = value
        self.equals = { $0 as? C == value }
        self.lessThan = { ($0 as? C).map { value < $0 } ?? false }
    }

    public static func < (lhs: AnyComparable, rhs: AnyComparable) -> Bool {
        lhs.lessThan(rhs.value) || (rhs != lhs && !rhs.lessThan(lhs.value))
    }
}
```

With that, you can write your `sort` method signature as:

```
mutating func sort(by criteria: (path: KeyPath<Element, AnyComparable>, order:OrderType)...) {
    
    
}
```

To make it easier for us to pass key paths with the type `AnyComparable` in, we can make an extension:

```
extension Comparable {
    // this name might be too long, but I'm sure you can come up with a better name
    var anyComparable: AnyComparable {
        .init(self)
    }
}
```

Now we can do:

```
someArray.sort(by: (\.key1.anyComparable, .asc), (\.key2.anyComparable, .asc))
```

Comment: Hm, ok, I didn't notice something is wrong, cause I didn't try sorting, but the general idea works for me. I tried this code, and sorting works nice. Thank you.