# Map enum to KeyPath to access properties in a generic way

Tags: swift, swift-keypath

I am trying to map enum values to properties on a struct, so the properties can be accessed by enum, and the properties can be iterated and processed in a generic way. Here is a contrived example, which demonstrates the compiler errors I'm getting:

```swift
import UIKit

protocol AProtocol: Equatable {
    var someInstanceProperty: String { get }
}

extension Bool: AProtocol {
    var someInstanceProperty: String { "Bool" }
}
extension Int: AProtocol {
    var someInstanceProperty: String { "Int" }
}
extension String: AProtocol {
    var someInstanceProperty: String { "String" }
}

struct Values {
    var someBool = false
    var someInt = 0
    var someString = "hello"
    
    enum Properties {
        case someB, someI, someS
    }
    
    let map1: [Properties: PartialKeyPath<Values>] = [
        .someB: \Values.someBool,
        .someI: \Values.someInt,
        .someS: \Values.someString,
    ]
    
    let map2: [Properties: KeyPath<Values, AProtocol>] = [
        .someB: \Values.someBool, // Cannot convert value of type 'KeyPath<Values, Bool>' to expected dictionary value type 'KeyPath<Values, AProtocol>'
        .someI: \Values.someInt, // Cannot convert value of type 'KeyPath<Values, Int>' to expected dictionary value type 'KeyPath<Values, AProtocol>'
        .someS: \Values.someString, // Cannot convert value of type 'KeyPath<Values, String>' to expected dictionary value type 'KeyPath<Values, AProtocol>'
    ]
    
    func performSomeAction<T: AProtocol>(key: Properties, keyPath: KeyPath<Values, T>) {
        print("key \(key), value \(self[keyPath: keyPath].someInstanceProperty)")
    }
    
    func getAll1() {
        for (key, keyPath) in map1 {
            performSomeAction(key: key, keyPath: keyPath) // Cannot convert value of type 'PartialKeyPath<Values>' to expected argument type 'KeyPath<Values, T>'
        }
    }
    
    func getAll2() {
        for (key, keyPath) in map1 {
            print("key \(key), value \(self[keyPath: keyPath].someInstanceProperty)") // Value of type 'Any?' has no member 'someInstanceProperty'
        }
    }
    
    func getAll3() {
        for (key, keyPath) in map1 {
            print("key \(key), value \((self[keyPath: keyPath] as! AProtocol).someInstanceProperty)") // Protocol 'AProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
        }
    }
}
```

In `map1`, the value type is `PartialKeyPath`. I can't use `KeyPath` because the value types are different (even though they all conform to `AProtocol`), so I get a compiler error (see `map2`). The problem with `map1` is that the values lose their type information. The three `getAll` functions demonstrate various approaches I've tried to overcome this, but haven't been successful. The closest I've got is `getAll3`, which works if I remove `Equatable` conformance from `AProtocol`. Unfortunately I need the values to be equatable – in my real code I'm comparing previously stored values with current property values. Is this possible?

Comment: If you just remove the `: Equatable` inheritance of your protocol, you won't get the "AProtocol can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements" error in `getAll3`. Is that something the protocol in your real code has to have?

Comment: Yes, not required in the example here of course, but I do require it in my real project. I'm comparing previously stored values with the current property values to determine which need updating.

Comment: Well, then you should probably redesign the whole thing (which I can't help you with without knowing more about what you are doing exactly). Equatable things of different types should not go into the same collection. You *can* technically work around it by making your own `AnyEquatable` [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68878549/5133585), but I don't think this is the best way to go.